# Running Ionic project using specific Node version

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, volta

I am trying to run an Ionic project using Node version `14.18.3`

I am using [Volta](https://docs.volta.sh/guide/) to set this version for this one particular project

To do this I ran this command:

```
volta pin node@14
```

If I navigate to my project and run `node -v` then I see `14.18.3`

When I try and build my project it fails and gives me an error that indicates that my node version is not 14

If I run `ionic info` then I see the following output. This shows that my node version is `16.13.1`

Question - where is `16.13.1` coming from? How do I get Ionic to run using node 14?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.18.1 (/Users/chris/.volta/tools/image/packages/@ionic/cli/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/chris/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v16.13.1 (/Users/chris/.volta/tools/image/node/16.13.1/bin/node)
   npm               : 8.2.0
   OS                : macOS Monterey
   Xcode             : Xcode 13.2.1 Build version 13C100
```

Comment: The usual culprits are ionic not seeing the `PATH` with the injected volta shims, or a module somewhere along the chain was installed with 16.13.1 and is referencing the 16 paths directly.  If you reinstall the projects deps under node 14 and run `./node_modules/.bin/ionic info` does it make any difference?

Comment: I'm opting to post this as a comment and not an answer, because I'm not perfectly sure of all the reasons for this behaviour... suffice to say, I've had very similar issues myself, and the only way I've got around them is to prepend `volta run --node <version> <command>`, where `<version>` is the NodeJS version you need to use, and `<command>` is what you were trying to run (like `ionic info`). hope that at least helps until you find a better solution..